# Getting incorrect data retrieved under a db field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query below:

```
SELECT sa.StudentId, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT StudentAnswer
ORDER BY StudentAnswer
SEPARATOR ',' ) AS StudentAnswer
FROM Student st
INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON ( st.StudentId = sa.StudentId )
INNER JOIN Student_Response sr ON ( sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId )
INNER JOIN Question q ON ( sr.QuestionId = q.QuestionId )
INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
LEFT JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
WHERE q.SessionId =27
GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId
```

The results it outputs is here:

[image]

Now I am planning to write a bigger query hence I am including all these tables in the `FROM`

But the issue in the results is the `StudentAnswer` column. It shows duplicate student answers for a student. This is incorrect as if I made the query slightly smaller by removing some tables from the `FROM` statement then it shows the correct student answers:

```
SELECT sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT StudentAnswer
ORDER BY StudentAnswer
SEPARATOR ',' ) AS StudentAnswer
FROM Student st
INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON ( st.StudentId = sa.StudentId )
INNER JOIN Question q ON ( sa.QuestionId = q.QuestionId )
WHERE q.SessionId =27
GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId
```

[image]

My question is ho can I get the correct student answers under the `StudentAnswer` column in the first query?

Below is the list of tables:

**Student:**

```
StudentId (PK auto)  StudentForename  StudentSurname 
39                   Luke             McFadzen
40                   Chris            Tucker
```

**Student_Answer:**

```
StudentAnswerId (PK auto)  QuestionId (FK Question)  StudentAnswer  StudentId (FK student)
1                          72                         D             39
2                          73                         B             39
3                          73                         C             39
4                          73                         D             39
5                          72                         C             40
6                          73                         A             40
7                          73                         C             40
8                          73                         E             40
```

**Student_Response:**

```
StudentResponseId (PK auto)  QuestionId (FK Question) ResponseTime  StudentId (FK student)
1                            72                       00:00:05      39
2                            73                       00:00:15      39
3                            72                       00:00:09      40
4                            73                       00:00:26      40
```

**Question:**

```
QuestionId (PK auto)  QuestionNo  SessionId (FK Session) ReplyId (FK Reply) OptionId (FK Option)    
72                    1           23                     1                  3
73                    2           23                     2                  7
```

**Answer:**

```
AnswerId (PK auto)    QuestionId (FK Question)      Answer  
1                          72                         C             
2                          73                         A             
3                          73                         C             
4                          73                         D
```

**Reply:**

```
ReplyId (PK auto)  ReplyType
1                  Single
2                  Multiple
```

**Option_Table:**

```
ReplyId (PK auto)  ReplyType
1                  A-C
2                  A-D
3                  A-E
4                  A-F
5                  A-G
6                  A-H
7                  A-I
8                  A-J
```

**FULL QUERY:**

```
SELECT
sa.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname, q.SessionId, q.QuestionId,
QuestionNo, QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, 
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer, r.ReplyType, QuestionMarks, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT StudentAnswer ORDER BY StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') AS StudentAnswer, ResponseTime, MouseClick, StudentMark
FROM Student st
INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON (st.StudentId = sa.StudentId)
INNER JOIN Student_Response sr ON (sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId)
INNER JOIN Question q ON (sr.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
LEFT JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
WHERE q.SessionId =27
GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId


Student - Student_Answer (StudentId)
Student - Student_Response (StudentId)
Student_Answer - Question (QuestionId)
Student_Response - Question (QuestionId)
Question - Answer (QuestionId)
Question - Reply (ReplyId)
Question - Option_Table (OptionId)
```

Comment: can you explain about the design? what does table `Response` does?

Comment: @JW. Response will get the time of the student's respone of selecting an answer per question. There are many more fields I have actually added into the query but I cut it down to just a couple of fields because the only field which was causing problems is the `StudentAnswer` field, but I do need all the tables in the `FROM` statement as in the full query each table in the `FROM` statement has a `SELECT` field to refer to

Comment: how about this? what's lacking? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/114ee/16

Comment: @JW. Do you want me to post you full query because I can see you have not included `Student_Response` table but there will be some fields in the SELECT which will belong to that table

Comment: can you also show how tables are connected with each other? that's the most important.

Comment: Ok included full query and beneath how atch table links to each other and the field's they are linked by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your query is already working, you only need to add this condition

```
SELECT  sa.StudentId
    ,   StudentForename
    ,   StudentSurname
    ,   q.SessionId
    ,   q.QuestionId
    ,   QuestionNo
    ,   o.OptionType
    ,   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',') AS Answer
    ,   r.ReplyType
    ,   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT StudentAnswer ORDER BY StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') AS StudentAnswer
    ,   ResponseTime
FROM    Student st
        INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa
            ON (st.StudentId = sa.StudentId)
        INNER JOIN Student_Response sr
            ON (sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId)
                AND sa.QuestionID = sr.QuestionID -- <<==lacking condition
        INNER JOIN Question q
            ON (sr.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
        INNER JOIN Answer an
            ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
        LEFT JOIN Reply r
            ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
        LEFT JOIN Option_Table o
            ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
GROUP   BY sa.StudentId , q.QuestionId;
```

Alternatively, you can can concatenate the values using subquery

```
SELECT  DISTINCT sa.StudentId
    ,   StudentForename
    ,   StudentSurname
    ,   q.SessionId
    ,   q.QuestionId
    ,   QuestionNo
    ,   o.OptionType
    ,   an.QuestionAnswer
    ,   r.ReplyType
    ,   sa.StudentAns
    ,   ResponseTime
FROM    Student st
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  StudentID, QuestionID,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(StudentAnswer ORDER BY StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') StudentAns
            FROM    Student_Answer
            GROUP   BY StudentID, QuestionID
        )sa ON (st.StudentId = sa.StudentId) 
        INNER JOIN Student_Response sr
            ON (sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId) AND sa.QuestionID = sr.QuestionID
        INNER JOIN Question q
            ON (sr.QuestionId = q.QuestionId) 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  QuestionID, 
                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer) QuestionAnswer
            FROM    Answer
            GROUP   BY QuestionID
        ) an
            ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
        LEFT JOIN Reply r
            ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
        LEFT JOIN Option_Table o
            ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f3e4/16)

Comment: which one do you prefer? `:D`

Comment: I would have to say the first one where you included an AND condition. But it is also helpful for me to see how a sub query operates as I have never done this before